# How can I put typed values in a specific element?

Tags: javascript

I've developed a simple game where I have an array of values and you need to guess it. When the value match, I show on a list using insertAdjacentHTML and appendChild. This is working very well. For example: Guess which countries already played a World Cup final.

But in this case, the list is filled in order of right answers.

[image: List filled with right answers (in order)]

I've wanted to upgrade this and display the answer on specific divs, so my idea is put the right answer on right order.

[image: How I wanted]

I tried to study about data-set-attribute, but I don't know how to set the value typed on a specific div yet.

For example, if I type Germany, I need to show the answer only on Germany answer div.

Any ideas?

Thank you so much!

```js
var validSearch = [
  "Brazil",
  "Germany",
  "Italy",
  "Argentine",
  "France",
  "Uruguay",
  "England",
  "Spain",
  "Netherlands",
  "Tchechoslovachia",
  "Hungary",
  "Sweden",
  "Croatia",
];

function sendToPage() {
  //get value and trim for unnecesary spaces, and set variable
  var q = document.getElementById("search").value.trim(),
    re,
    result;

  //return if textbox is empty
  if (!q.length > 0) {
    return;
  }

  //set RegExp (indexOf is faster but Case Sensitive)
  re = new RegExp(".*" + q.replace(/\s/g, "\\s") + ".*", "ig");

  //start searching
  validSearch.some(function(v) {
    result = re.exec(v);
    if (result) {
      //Remove from array the right answers
      validSearch.splice(validSearch.indexOf(result[0]), 1);
      return true;
    }
  });

  //if match
  if (result !== null) {
    var el = document.createElement("li");
    el.classList = "respostas";
    el.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", result[0]);
    var container = document.querySelector("#right-answers");
    container.appendChild(el);
  } else {
    alert("Try Again! - " + q);
  }

  //refresh input box
  document.getElementById("search").value = "";
  document.getElementById("search").focus();
}
```

```html
<div class="barra-widget">
  <div>
    <button onclick="startTimer()" id="start">Start</button>
  </div>

  <div class="guess-bar">
    <div class="guess-bar-input">
      <input id="search" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Insert Country Here" disabled>
      <button onclick="sendToPage()" id="guess" disabled>Guess!</button>
    </div>

    <div class="guess-timer">
      <span id="count">90</span> sec
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ol id="right-answers"></ol>
```

Comment: Please revise the demo above so it shows the problem. You might remove the click handler from the Start button and enable it.

Comment: Have you looked at `innerText` and `innerHTML` properties of node elements? On divs you can simply set `innerText` to whatever you want or `innerHTML` to any html you want, through javascript. It is an essential part of beginner level dom manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that while also removing items from your `validSearch` is by creating all the `li` elements initially while your array has all the indexes. You set a `data-answer` to each `li` and then you proceed in removing the element from array. I would suggest doing this one time though and not every time someone is pushing the guess button.

From there, when someone inputs a correct value, it gets removed from the array, then gets matched with the specified `li` element that has the same `data-answer`. Then it sets the class to `.respostas` and the `innerText` of the element to the answer itself.

Let me know if this worked.

```js
var validSearch = [
  "Brazil",
  "Germany",
  "Italy",
  "Argentine",
  "France",
  "Uruguay",
  "England",
  "Spain",
  "Netherlands",
  "Tchechoslovachia",
  "Hungary",
  "Sweden",
  "Croatia",
];

function sendToPage() {
  //get value and trim for unnecesary spaces, and set variable
  var q = document.getElementById("search").value.trim(),
    re,
    result;

  //return if textbox is empty
  if (!q.length > 0) return;

  // Create Answer Slots initially
  if (!document.querySelector('#right-answers li')) {
    validSearch.forEach(validAnswer => {
      var elem = document.createElement('li');
      elem.setAttribute('data-answer', `${validAnswer}`);
      document.querySelector('#right-answers').appendChild(elem);
    });
  }

  //set RegExp (indexOf is faster but Case Sensitive)
  re = new RegExp(".*" + q.replace(/\s/g, "\\s") + ".*", "ig");

  //start searching
  validSearch.some(function(v) {
    result = re.exec(v);
    if (result) {
      validSearch.splice(validSearch.indexOf(result[0]), 1);
      return true;
    }
  });

  //if match
  if (result !== null) {
    const match = document.querySelector(`[data-answer="${result[0]}"]`);
    match.classList.add("respostas");
    match.innerText = result[0];
  } else {
    alert("Try Again! - " + q);
  }

  //refresh input box
  document.getElementById("search").value = "";
  document.getElementById("search").focus();
}
```

```html
<div class="barra-widget">
  <div>
    <button onclick="startTimer()" id="start">Start</button>
  </div>

  <div class="guess-bar">
    <div class="guess-bar-input">
      <input id="search" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Insert Country Here">
      <button onclick="sendToPage()" id="guess">Guess!</button>
    </div>

    <div class="guess-timer">
      <span id="count">90</span> sec
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ol id="right-answers"></ol>
```

### How it should be done performance-wise

On DOM load, append all the `li` elements and do not include this in the guess button onclick code:

```js
var validSearch = [
  "Brazil",
  "Germany",
  "Italy",
  "Argentine",
  "France",
  "Uruguay",
  "England",
  "Spain",
  "Netherlands",
  "Tchechoslovachia",
  "Hungary",
  "Sweden",
  "Croatia",
];

function fillList() {
  validSearch.forEach(validAnswer => {
    var elem = document.createElement('li');
    elem.setAttribute('data-answer', `${validAnswer}`);
    document.querySelector('#right-answers').appendChild(elem);
  });
}

function sendToPage() {
  //get value and trim for unnecesary spaces, and set variable
  var q = document.getElementById("search").value.trim(),
    re,
    result;

  //return if textbox is empty
  if (!q.length > 0) return;

  //set RegExp (indexOf is faster but Case Sensitive)
  re = new RegExp(".*" + q.replace(/\s/g, "\\s") + ".*", "ig");

  //start searching
  validSearch.some(function(v) {
    result = re.exec(v);
    if (result) {
      validSearch.splice(validSearch.indexOf(result[0]), 1);
      return true;
    }
  });

  //if match
  if (result !== null) {
    const match = document.querySelector(`[data-answer="${result[0]}"]`);
    match.classList.add("respostas");
    match.innerText = result[0];
  } else {
    alert("Try Again! - " + q);
  }

  //refresh input box
  document.getElementById("search").value = "";
  document.getElementById("search").focus();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  fillList();
});
```

```html
<div class="barra-widget">
  <div>
    <button onclick="startTimer()" id="start">Start</button>
  </div>

  <div class="guess-bar">
    <div class="guess-bar-input">
      <input id="search" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Insert Country Here">
      <button onclick="sendToPage()" id="guess">Guess!</button>
    </div>

    <div class="guess-timer">
      <span id="count">90</span> sec
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ol id="right-answers"></ol>
```

Comment: Hi George! I understand the main idea and I will try to use this tips. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Marcio if any of the solutions helped you, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the set of available answers as list items hiding their display value, you could still rely on the `<ol>` and `<li>` elements since they are more appropriate in terms of semantics.

To achieve that, you can Initialize the page with a function that will run on document ready, reading the `answers` array and populating such list in a way that each item will have an empty content but will hold data coming from the answer item.

In this demo I chose to keep track for each item of the following information in corresponding data attributes stored in the element:

- `index` - the index of the answer relative to the array
- `value` - the exact value in the array
- `key` - the value in lower case

When the user will try to guess a word, the code will try to find a list item element using the selector:

```
#right-answers > li[data-key=guessedValueToLowerCase]`);
```

Trying to find any list item having an attribute `data-key` with the value as the guessed word to lower case.

If the element is found, the css class `correctly-guessed` will be added to it and its content will be filled with the value coming from `data-value`.

Just for the sake of completeness I tried to match the style you showed in the pictures... but with not a too much effort. Plus the counter is not engaged and the game cannot be reset.

The demo is just meant to show the strategy to show all the answer and reveal them once they are correctly guessed

```js
var answers = [
  "Brazil",
  "Germany",
  "Italy",
  "Argentine",
  "France",
  "Uruguay",
  "England",
  "Spain",
  "Netherlands",
  "Tchechoslovachia",
  "Hungary",
  "Sweden",
  "Croatia",
];

initGame(answers);

function initGame(answers){
  const answersContainer = document.getElementById('right-answers');
  for(let i=0;i<answers.length;i++){
    const answer = answers[i];
    var answerElement = document.createElement("li");            
    answerElement.dataset.index = i;
    answerElement.dataset.key = answer.toLowerCase();
    answerElement.dataset.value = answer;        
    answersContainer.appendChild(answerElement);
  }
  
  document.getElementById('guess')
    .addEventListener('click', event => {
      const guessedWord = document.getElementById('search').value;
      guessWord(guessedWord);
    });  
}

function startTimer(){
  document.getElementById('search').disabled = false;
  document.getElementById('guess').disabled = false;
}

function guessWord(word) {  
  
  const answerElement = document.querySelector(`#right-answers > li[data-key=${word.toLowerCase()}]`);
  
  if (answerElement) {      
    answerElement.classList.add('correctly-guessed');
  } else {
    alert(`Try Again! - The word guessed '${word}' is wrong.`);
  }

  //refreshes input box
  document.getElementById("search").value = "";
  document.getElementById("search").focus();
}
```

```css
body{
  background: purple;
}

.barra-widget{
  padding: 20px;
}

.guess-bar{
  text-align: center;
}

.guess-bar-input,
.guess-timer{
  display: inline-block;
}

#search{
  font-size: 20px;
  background: white;
}

#guess{
  font-size: 20px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

#right-answers {
  /*list-style: none;*/
}

#right-answers li{    
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: violet;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: italic;
}

#right-answers li.correctly-guessed:after{
  content: attr(data-value);
}
```

```html
<div class="barra-widget">
  
  <div>
    <button onclick="startTimer()" id="start">Start</button>
  </div>

  <div class="guess-bar">
    <div class="guess-bar-input">
      <input id="search" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Insert Country Here" disabled>
      <button id="guess" disabled>Guess!</button>
    </div>

    <div class="guess-timer">
      <span id="count">90</span> sec
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <ol id="right-answers"></ol>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the best solution for my case!

Comment: I see you also received an other answer that achieves the same result. I just spent some more efforts on the presentation. By the way I also invite you to mark the most suitable answer as correct and possibly reward any helpful answer with an upvote also to show gratitude and respect to anyone willing to spend their time to your problem.. only as long as the information made you richer on topic